# WebSocket frequent onmessage zero-copy

Tags: javascript, memory-management, browser, websocket, garbage-collection

I have an app that receives binary messages over a WebSocket frequently (at least once per frame) and plots the data, using canvas/webgl. I've noticed that I have a pretty good saw-tooth memory profile; lots of short lived chunks of data.
[image]

This does not surprise me since I'm receiving an object from `onmessage`, at least once every 16ms, which is used for drawing and then de-referenced.

My question is: are there any tips for avoiding/minimizing this? Based on the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket), there doesn't seem to be an alternative to having new memory allocated on every socket receive call. In another language/environment, I'd pre-allocate some memory and receive into that buffer, to avoid constantly allocating memory for short lived objects, but I can't think of any obvious way to achieve this in JavaScript in the browser.

For reference, here is my Frames view.

[image]

I don't know if that idle time is garbage collection? Any dev-tools ninja insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you got any code sample ? have started something ? a fiddle ?

Comment: I have the same problem streaming sensor date from my raspberry pi over WebSockets. I'm afraid there is and will be no way to interfere memory allocation of WebSockets in javascript. My research has not brought any results.

Comment: What do you hope to achieve? How long does the program run and how important is consistent, long lived performance?  Seeing a little code or a code sample would be great

Comment: My question is for others who have had to solve a similar problem: receiving lots of asynchronous data, often. It doesn't appear that the WebSocket provides any way to manage memory at the socket receive level (zero-copy). I know there are applications out there with this basic functionality: is there a way to be smarter about copying memory in the browser?

Comment: how tall are the teeth on the wave? if your'e talking about 5mb, no prob, if it's 500mb, then yeah, it needs fixed. also post your render pipeline, i bet there are objects that can avoid being created (and collected later), often from unexpected places, like [].map/filter(). you need those 60 tiny objects per second, but they should not weigh very much, there likely something else going on...

Comment: @dandavis, I just ran a profile and am seeing: **Used JS Heap [259172488:274765862]**. Is that the range in bytes? I have minimized any variable declaration, object creation inside the `requestAnimationFrame()` loop. Not using any array iteration functions, straight `for()` loops...

Comment: `(259172488-274765862).toLocaleString()` shows a 15mb range. that's actually not that bad for such a heavy app, and there is no steady increase over time. in short, it looks just fine; chrome uses a fair amount of memory; even this very page uses 64mb, so even on it, a 23% swing would be interesting but not alarming, and it's not doing thousands of things a minute...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood your problem but you can declare a global array like in any other language and use it as a circular buffer, for example:

```
var buffer = [];
var bufferLength = 1000;
var start = 0;
var end = 0;
var content = 0;

socket.onmessage(function(msg) { //msg allocated
    end %= bufferLength;
    if (end == start && content != 0)
        console.log("Buffer is full");
    else {
        content++;
        buffer[end++] = msg; //reference to msg saved so it's not destroyed at the end of the callback
    }
});

function getNext() {
    start %= bufferLength;
    if (start == end && content == 0)
        console.log("Buffer is empty");
    else {
        content--;
        return buffer[start++]; // returns reference to next msg
    }
}
```

Edit: I modified the answer to be more clear about the memory cycle:

JS will allocate memory for the received message on websockets and will create a reference to it called `msg` that will be given to you as a param in the callback defined for `onmessage`.

Note JS GC will only destroy that memory piece when it is not referenced anymore in the code.

What I do above is saving that reference inside a buffer so the value does not get destroyed when the callback is done and you can access it later using `getNext`. You don't need to allocate new memory because JS did it for you.

In case you want to clone or create a different copy of `msg`, there are some different options. A simple option that will allow you to clone a non-circular JSON object would be:

```
var newJSON = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
```

You can find more information about memory allocation in JS in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_Management

Comment: That doesn't answer my question, which is specifically in regard to "new memory allocated on every socket receive call".

Comment: I'm concerned specifically with the memory allocated for the object passed to `onmessage`: `msg`. I think you are misunderstanding my question. I'm asking for a way to pre-allocate a buffer that the WebSocket or perhaps some other API will use to receive into from the underlying socket.

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem now. I don't think you can do anything about it using JS. You may be able to mitigate some of the total delay enabling zero-copy rasterizer in chrome chrome://flags/#enable-zero-copy so it renders faster in webgl. Also, given your problem is about memory access, you can play with the number/size of the packets sent from the server, less/bigger packets will reduce the number of operations.